# encoding a word given an alphabet in java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a method that allows me to pass a word to numbers taking into account an array of chars this is my method and the alphabet given:

```
public static final char[] CHARACTERS_SPACE = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '};
```

```
public static void codificate(String msg) {
    char[] msgChar = msg.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> msgToNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < CHARACTERS_SPACE.length; i++) {
        for (char c : msgChar) {
            if (CHARACTERS_SPACE[i] == c){
                msgToNumbers.add(c);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(msgToNumbers.toString());
    }
}
```

However, when I compare it and print the array, I get the word sorted. For example, if I want to code the word "acbd" the output is: [A,B,C,D] I don't know how I could do so that the word is returned in the correct order.

I don't know what I could try to do to perform this method, since I don't understand why the word is commanding me.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in case of `"abcd"`, what *should* be the correct order of the output? Because what your algorithm does is basically transforming a String into an ArrayList of characters. Do you actually want to convert your word into full ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need to be done here for this to work. The characters you want to convert to are all uppercase but the supplied message string is in lower case. in order to carry out a comparison for equality, they both must be of the same letter case. With this in mind changing the code line `if (CHARACTERS_SPACE[i] == c){` to something like this: `if (charactersSpace[i] == Character.toUpperCase(c)) {` would be more benificial to the overall task..

Also, within the same `if` block,  what should be added to the `msgToNumber` ArrayList (a decieving variable name) is not `c` but instead it should be `CHARACTERS_SPACE[i]`. A `break;` statement could also be added directly under the now `msgToNumbers.add(CHARACTERS_SPACE[i]);` since the character has already been found and no more iterations of the inner loop is required for the current character. This would help speed things up a wee bit.

So to maintain the order of the characters in the supplied `msg` string, the inner `for` loop declaration should  moved so to constitute an outer loop. In other words the outer and inner loop declarations should swap positions, for example:

```
public static void codificate(String msg) {
    String chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";   
    final char[] charactersSpace = chars.toCharArray();
    
    char[] msgChar = msg.toCharArray();
    List<Character> msgToNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char c : msgChar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < charactersSpace.length; i++) {
            if (charactersSpace[i] == Character.toUpperCase(c)) {
                msgToNumbers.add(charactersSpace[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(msgToNumbers);
}
```

Notice also where the code line `System.out.println(msgToNumbers);` was moved to.... outside the outer `for` loop. This is so that the `msgToNumbers` list is not printed to the Console Window upon every outer loop iteration.

---

**On A Side:**

If you want the above method to return a String instead of doing the console print from within the method then you can change like this:

```
public static String codificate(String msg) {
    String chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";   
    final char[] charactersSpace = chars.toCharArray();
    
    char[] msgChar = msg.toCharArray();
    List<Character> msgToNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char c : msgChar) {
        for (int i = 0; i < charactersSpace.length; i++) {
            if (charactersSpace[i] == Character.toUpperCase(c)) {
                msgToNumbers.add(charactersSpace[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return msgToNumbers.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\], ]", "");
}
```

And you might use the method like this:

```
String str = codificate("adcb");
System.out.println(str);
```

The Console Window will display:

ADCB